# Meaning of a symbol regarding field.

Tags: field-theory, notation, galois-theory, galois-extensions

I was going through a problem in Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra*. That problem involves two subfields $K$ and $E$, and $K=Q(a^{1/n})$. In that problem they have a hint that $N_{K/E}(a^{1/n})\in E$.  I have never seen the last symbol  $N_{K/E}(a^{1/n})$. It will be really great if someone can tell me what this symbol means.

Comment: What page is the problem on?

Comment: Page 636 question 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On pages 581 - 582, it is defined in Exercise 17:

Let $K/F$ be any finite extension and let $\alpha\in K$. Let $L$ be a Galois extension of $F$ containing $K$ and let $H \leq \text{Gal}(L/F)$ be the subgroup corresponding to $K$. Define the *norm* of $\alpha$ from $K$ to $F$ to be
$$
N_{K/F}(\alpha) = \prod_{\sigma}\sigma(\alpha),
$$
where the product is taken over all the embeddings of $K$ into an algebraic closure of $F$.

Comment: Ohhhh okay okay. Thank you so much. I couldn't find it when I searched it in the Google also. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, I found it by stumbling through the exercises in the Galois theory chapter (it appears that Dummit & Foote often introduce definitions in the exercises themselves). Some symbols appear in the list right at the start of the book, but this one didn't unfortunately.